# How to generate SOAP Header?

Tags: web-services, authentication, soap, wsdl

I have one external WSDL from where i am that wasdl and will extract the data from there and when i am hitting that wsdl getting error as The  is empty in your request. Username token is missing from there. You need to generate the username token and add it to the header. so we need to generate username token  as below sample, my concern is how to generate soap:header. The password digest is comprised of the password, create time and nonce value as follows:
Password_Digest = Base64 ( SHA-1 ( nonce + created + password ) )

Answer (score 0):

You can see the solution of the OSCM Service Catalog, the code creates a SOAP header with version information in it. 
https://github.com/servicecatalog/development/blob/master/oscm-apiversioning-client-handler/javasrc/org/oscm/apiversioning/handler/VersionHandler.java

More about Open Source Project [OSCM Cloud Services Management Software](http://openservicecatalogmanager.org/ui/)